# loop over columns and display results

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to loop over a table in oracle, find the null values in each column, and then update those values, 
for now I am trying to just output the number of null values in each column, but i'm getting an error message :

```
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
   N_NULLS       NUMBER;
   BEGIN
   FOR I IN (SELECT COLUMN_NAME
               FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
              WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'my_table')
   LOOP
          SELECT SUM (CASE WHEN I IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        INTO N_NULLS
        FROM my_table
       WHERE COLUMN_ITEM IS NULL;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('NUMBER OF NULLS IN'|| I ||' IS ' || N_NULLS);
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I get the following errors :

```
Error at line 10
ORA-06550: line 9, column 23:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 9, column 8:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 10, column 29:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
```

Comment: `SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'` will return something like `ID` or `FIRSTNAME`. `column_name` will **never** be `NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@a_horse_with_no_name is correct, you can try the below code to find empty rows in columns of a particular table.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
    l_sql     VARCHAR2(4000);
    n_nulls   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (
        SELECT
            column_name
        FROM
            all_tab_columns
        WHERE
            table_name = 'my_table'
    ) LOOP
        l_sql := ' SELECT SUM (CASE WHEN '
         || i.column_name
         || ' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        FROM my_table
       WHERE '
         || i.column_name
         || ' IS NULL';

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql INTO
            n_nulls;
        dbms_output.put_line('NUMBER OF NULLS IN'
         || i.column_name
         || ' IS '
         || n_nulls);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(CASE WHEN I IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

should be

```
(CASE WHEN I.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Same issue here:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('NUMBER OF NULLS IN'|| I ||' IS ' || N_NULLS);
```